# Automatically expanding sliders in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Is there some way to have all sliders expanded by default in a Manipulator object, i.e. as if I had clicked all "+" signs?

Comment: Are you trying to do `Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}, Appearance -> { "Open", "Labeled"}]` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As David Slater comments you can specify this with the `Appearance` option:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 0}, 0, 1, Appearance -> {"Open"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) on `Manipulate`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, this works. My Manipulator has lots of sliders: is there a method to open them all at once?

Comment: @nccc Not that I know of, but I'll look.

Answer (score 13):

To get the "Open" setting globally, by analogy with [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32848/can-manipulate-controls-have-the-option-appearance-labeled-by-default):

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Open"]
```