# Can Manipulate controls have the option Appearance -> "Labeled" by default?

Tags: manipulate, options

I was wondering if there's a way to tell Mathematica to use the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` for all `Manipulate` commands by default. I use this option quite often and it would be very convenient if I could set it to be the default behaviour

Comment: `SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Labeled"]` but this works for one type of control ofc :)

Comment: @Kuba Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Because it isn't the answer. :) One still has to do this for `Silder`s etc. But I will try to put more extended answer unless something very neat appear.

Comment: @Kuba -- SetOptions seems to work for sliders. Use your code, then `Manipulate[a^2, {a, 1, 10}]`, and you have the appearance labeled.

Comment: @bills This is `Manipulator`, try `Manipulate[a^2, {a, 1, 10, Slider}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was hesitating but it seems some people find this information useful.

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
Manipulate[{a, b, c},
           {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

But, still, I do not consider it the full answer. Like it is stated, it affects only `Manipulator`, the default control used by `Manipulate` for domains that are suited for slider-like controls.

Unfortunatelly, undesired behaviour appears in case of other controls. Of course not each has `Appearance` option, but even though `Slider` do, something strange happens:

```
SetOptions[Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
Manipulate[{a, b, c},
           {a, 1, 10},
           {b, 1, 10}, 
           {c, 1, 10, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
           ControlType -> Slider]
```

[image]

I guess it's not something we can easily win with in general :) [How can I work with `SetOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/5478)

but in this case, thanks to [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov), one can use

```
 Manipulate[{a, b, c},
           {a, 1, 10},
           {b, 1, 10}, 
           {c, 1, 10}, 
           ControlType -> LabeledSlider]
```

---

I think that sometimes `Slider` is better than `Manipulator`, the latter gives too much control for the users of applications so the may break something :P. Quick fix that works with the method I've shown is:

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Labeled", AppearanceElements -> None]
```

Comment: Good enough for my vote. :-)  Improve it later if you think of something better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I will if I find. I'm also looking forward to seeing some MichaelE2-style spelunking :)

Comment: If you type ``?DynamicDump`ControlToBoxes`` you can see exact definition ``DynamicDump`ControlToBoxes[Slider[BoxForm`a___,Appearance->Labeled,BoxForm`b___],BoxForm`fmt_]:=DynamicDump`ControlToBoxes[LabeledSlider[BoxForm`a,BoxForm`b],BoxForm`fmt]``. Therefore `Slider` doesn't take into account the default options. However there is `LabeledSlider`!