# How to expand the parameter bar in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

When running `Manipulate` the parameter bar is initially not expanded.
How can I make all the parameter bars expanded all at once like the image below?

[image]

Comment: If this will be considered a duplicate I will gladly delete my answer: [**32848**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32848/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Open"];

Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

[image]