# How do I globally set control widths?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I have controls in a `Manipulate` that I'm laying out in a `Grid` and I'd like globally set their widths (and other properties). For example, something like

```
Grid[{{Control@{{sx3, 1}, -10, 10}, ...}]
```

but

```
SetOptions[Slider,{ImageSize-> 150, Appearance->"UpArrow"}]
```

has no effect; and

```
ctl[c_]:=Control[Join[c,{ImageSize->150, Appearance->"UpArrow"}]]
Grid[{{ctl@{{sx3, 1}, -10, 10}, ...}]
```

gives errors.

The only approach that works is to set these options for each control with

```
Grid[{{Control@{{sx3, 1}, -10, 10, ImageSize-> 150, Appearance->"UpArrow"}, ...}]
```

How do I globally set control widths (inside of `Grid`), and other properties so that I can avoid having to set them for each of my controls individually?

Comment: because it is not a `Slider`, try `SetOptions[Manipulator, {ImageSize -> 220, Appearance -> "UpArrow"}]`

Comment: related: [32848](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32848/5478)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Kuba point out, the default slider-like control for `Manipulate` is actually a `Manipulator`, so you can do it like this.

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, {ImageSize -> 150, Appearance -> "UpArrow"}];
Manipulate[
 {a, b, c, d},
 Grid[
   Map[
     Control,
     {{{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}}, {{c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}}},
     {-2}]]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Yes, as @Kuba pointed out.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. I have given him credit.

Answer (score 1):

You can globally define

```
slide = 
  Slider[##, Appearance -> {Tiny, "UpArrow"}, Background -> GrayLevel[0.95]] &;
```

And then inside a `Manipulate`

```
Grid[{
  {"Lines", Control[{{nl, 4, ""}, 1, 128, 1, slide}]},
  {"Length", Control[{{sc, 0.5, ""}, 0.02, 2, 0.02, slide}]},
  {"Range", Control[{{rf, 1, ""}, 0.5, 2, slide}]}
  }, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {0.5, 1.2}]
```

[image]

Similarily with other controls.

Inside constructs like `Grid`, `Column` etc. you must use `Control`.

Comment: That still requires placing what is effectively a setting in each `Control` (albeit as a package).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `ctl` function work with something like this:

```
Attributes[ctl] = HoldFirst;
ctl[{para__}] := Control[{para, ImageSize -> 150, Appearance -> "UpArrow"}]

Grid[{{ctl@{{sx3, 1}, -10, 10}}}]
```